# Cakephp 3 : Plugin’s rooting in a prefix

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem with routing. I have a plugin but I can not connect a route in a prefix.

Plugins url : /plugin-name/test : call TestController in "pluginsName/TestController.php"

I wan't
/myprefix/plugin-name/test : call TestController in "pluginsName/TestController.php

My differents test :

```
<?php
Router::prefix('myprefix', function ($routes) {
    // Call TestController in my plugin but in "pluginsName/Api/TestController.php"
    $routes->connect('/plugin-name/test', ['plugin' => 'PluginName', 'controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'display']);

    // Error
    $routes->connect('/plugin-name/test', ['plugin' => 'PluginName', 'controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'display', 'prefix'=>false]);

     Not work
     $routes->plugin('PluginName', function($routes) {
         $routes->connect('/test', ['controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'display']);
       });

});
```

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Should be work.

```
Router::plugin('Contacts', ['_namePrefix' => 'contacts:'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->scope('/api', ['_namePrefix' => 'api:'], function ($routes) {
        // This route's name will be `contacts:api:ping`
        $routes->connect('/ping', ['controller' => 'Pings'], ['_name' => 'ping']);
    });
});
```

It will make, the URL `/contacts/api/ping` will redirect to Contacts plugin with pings controller.

For example:

```
 Router::plugin('Contacts', ['_namePrefix' => 'contacts:'], function ($routes) {  
        // This route's name will be `contacts:ping`
        $routes->connect('/ping', ['controller' => 'Pings'], ['_name' => 'ping']);

});
```

It will redirect to Contact plugin and Pings controller like `/contacts/ping`.

Comment: Thank you but I wanted to be like url `/api/contacts/ping` with the controller ping in `src/plugin/contacts/controller/PingController`. I have done differently.